# Why does Cards insist on charging an international price when both addressees are in the US?

Tags: cards-app

Although I reside in Austin, TX, I'm currently in Europe and wanted to send my father in New York a birthday card. As soon as I enter his address in Cards, the price changes to $4.99! Even though both the sender's and recipient's address are in the USA, Cards (via Location Services) probably wants to send the card from France, which is absurd!

Isn't there a workaround for this? Would disabling location services and waiting 24 hours work?

Answer (score 3):

The problem was this: under Settings > General > International > Region Format, I had selected France because that's where I currently am. Why this influences the price when the combination of addresses should be the sole determining factor is beyond me. Once I had set the region format back to "United States," I was able to purchase a card for $2.99.